# Accessing Remote Desktop without Terminal Services on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, terminal-server, licensing

We have a Windows 2003 server that out of the box we installed and ran Terminal Services.  Now however the trial period is over and I am getting an error looking for a licence.

> ### Remote Desktop Disconnected
>
> The remote session was disconnected because there
>   are no Terminal Server License Servers
>   available to provide a license.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator.

All I really need it Remote Administration Services or Remote Desktop on my server which I believe doesnt require any additional licences.  However I cant seem to get this to work while TS is still running and installed.

Stuff I've tried.

- Remote Desktop Connections are enabled
- I tried to stop the terminal services service but I couldn't.
- I looked at uninstalling terminal services, but it says anything I installed after it was switched uon would need to be reinstalled (!!!!!).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall Terminal Services. Windows Server has Admin RDP built in w/o TS.

Uninstalling/Reinstall usually isn't necessary, though some apps might break. It depends on what you have installed.

On a professional note: You should be carefully planning your server deployments, installing only what is necessary for the server to serve it's function. You should not be installing just any Windows service that sound interesting, nor applications that aren't absolutely necessary. You should understand the ramifications of each installation and carefully evaluate the benefits thereof. Running stable, efficient, and productive servers is not something that happens on accident. Good administrators earn their pay by understanding these .relationships and providing ever increasing value to their company through excellent implementation.

Comment: This, right here, should be the Admin Bible.  

Also, Terminal Services is a role, and can be added, configured, and removed though the "Server Manager" menu.  If memory serves, you can also enable Remote Desktop for Administration from Server Manager as well, once you've removed TS and rebooted the box.  One-stop shop.